# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: mysql

Tengo mi base de datos y mi código en un servidor remoto.
Lo he mantenido funcionando hace tiempo y no había ningún problema (podía conectarme a la base de datos, insertar y actualizar datos), pero ayer luego de una consulta dejó de funcionar y en las métricas de mi servidor ví que la utilización de la CPU llegó a un 90%.
Ahora funciona mi aplicación, pero no me puedo conectar a la base de datos.
Intenté los siguientes comandos y estos son los mensajes:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p status
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
```

Intenté abrir el archivo mysql.sock, pero no pude.

```
sudo service mysqld start
Unit mysqld.service not found.

systemctl start mysql
Failed to start mysql.service: Access denied
```

Ví que a algunos les ha funcionado reinstalar mysql, pero no sé como puedo rescatar mi base de datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verifica que el puerto de mysql, 3306 este abierto porque mysql usa ese puerto para su conexión con el cliente que es el que estas usando.

Reinicia el servicio de mysql.

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

También reinicia el servidor, muchas veces es un mareo del motor de mysql pero es muy raro que esto pase

Comment: Tenía abierto el puerto 3306, reinicié el servidor y no funcionó. Con el comando que me diste me dio el error "Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.". Luego borré el puerto 3306 y lo cree de nuevo y ahora funciona. No tengo idea por qué, pero gracias!